# How to fix NDK build error in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want build my project from Android Studio into my phone, but when I hit the run button in Android Studio, it shows me this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
or use the experimental plugin:
 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.
```

**Build.Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companyname.gamename"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the below code in your *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file (Module:app):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

buildTypes{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in file *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* above `buildTypes{}`:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

buildTypes {
}
```

Comment: Even if less than 2 minutes apart, this answer was probably plagiarised from [AskNilesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535568/how-to-fix-ndk-build-error-in-android-studio/44535613#44535613).